# Parallel For loop versus simple for loop in c#. Speed test

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel.for

I have some doubt as to whether I should use a Parallel.For(). I did a simple test and it came out strongly against parallelization. In what cases and how to properly use Parallel.For() and PLinq? Here is my test code:

```
class Wrapper
{
    public void Sequential()
    {
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            DauntingOp(i);
            DauntingOp(i + 9000);
            DauntingOp(i - 8521);
            DauntingOp(i);
            DauntingOp(i + 9000);
            DauntingOp(i - 8521);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("For = ms: {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }

    public void ParallelFor()
    {
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        Parallel.For(0, 1000, (elem) => 
        {
            DauntingOp(elem);
            DauntingOp(elem + 9000);
            DauntingOp(elem - 8521);
            DauntingOp(elem);
            DauntingOp(elem + 9000);
            DauntingOp(elem - 8521);
        });

        Console.WriteLine("Parallel For = ms: {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }

    private void DauntingOp(int index)
    {
        try
        {
            long val = index;
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                long a = val + 345678;
                long b = a + 4567;
                long c = a - b;
                long d = long.Parse(new Random().Next().ToString());
                long x = d - a - b - c;
                long y = long.Parse(new Random().Next().ToString()) - (long.Parse(new Random().NextDouble().ToString()) + 345 - x);
            }
        }
        catch { }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                long a = 345678;
                long b = a + 4567;
                long c = a - b;
                long d = long.Parse(new Random().Next().ToString());
                long x = d - a - b - c;
                long y = long.Parse(new Random().Next().ToString()) - (long.Parse(new Random().Next().ToString()) + 345 - x);
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }

}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper();
        wrapper.Sequential();
        wrapper.ParallelFor();

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Results:

```
For = ms: 22645
Parallel For = ms: 29020
```

Should not be Parallel.For faster?

Comment: I would say that the cost of managing the parallel loop is outweighing the cost of the work being done in this case. If you were doing something that took longer, e.g. connecting to a db and inserting some records in a transaction, then you might find the parallel loop is faster. BTW, for the cases where you pass i + 9000 to your DauntingOp, the method will not execute anything in the try since index is already 1000+, so those calls won't add anything meaningful to your tests.

Comment: I ran your code on my machine and the difference was marginal. I have just enabled multiple cores; I'll reboot and try again, then get back to you.

Comment: It depends on how many cores your CPU has. If its single core then parallel one will work slower due to overhead on thread context switching.

Comment: Check this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/e7wx99, I had to reduce the number of iterations, but the Parallel for is faster there too (most of the time)

Comment: I'd probably do something with the results of the runs and re-evaluate. For fun, try running your program in Release mode. I got `For = ms: 344` and `Parallel For = ms: 94`. It got nearly all optimized away.

Comment: You have only demonstrated how difficult benchmarking can be. You should at least have posted the hardware and compiler settings. What counts most is the 'work' inside the body, your test code is too small and could be optimized away towards a NOP.

Comment: I don't understand why this question has so many downvotes. The test was large enough for the results to be conclusive: surprisingly so, as the operation doesn't really look that daunting.

Comment: @RobLyndon: No, the test wasn't large enough and it wasn't controlled enough. And even if this benchmark was improved it's still just one synthetic test. There is no general answer for `for(;;)` vs `Parallel.For()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the solution in release mode without debugging.

My system has four cores, which I can see using Task Manager:

[image]

And the benchmarking is reliably four times faster:

[image]

Note that you won't have multiple cores enabled in Windows 10 by default. You have to run msconfig from your Start menu, and enable multiple processors in the Boot menu:

[image]

Comment: It's strange. The boot options I switched the number of processors on 8. My processor is i7 3632QM 2.2GHz - 4/8 cores. I ran the program in release mode with debugger - similar results. But the release mode without the debugger:

Comment: Parallel For = ms: 18
For = ms: 29

Comment: Apologies if I'm stating the blindingly obvious, but you did reboot after changing the boot options, right?

Comment: That BOOT option only applies to the booting process. It should not affect this benchmark.

Comment: Yes, reboot after - it was forced by the windows. And i think it should affect only the booting process ... But obviously i missed influence of debbuger.